# Ownership sharing with smart pointers while object initialization

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, ownership-semantics, enable-shared-from-this

I have a class `A` that has a member pointer to class `B`:

```
class A 
{
public: 
    A() 
    {
        m_b = createB();
    }
    std::shared<B> getSpB()
    {
        return m_b;
    }
private:
    std::shared<B> m_b;
};

class B 
{
public: 
    B() {}

    static std::shared_ptr<B> createB()
    {
        return std::make_shared<B>();
    }
    void func1() {/* ... */ }

private:
};
```

In my `main` function I create a `shared_ptr` of class `A` and then use some methods of both classes.

```
int main() 
{
    auto spA = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto spB = spA->getSpB();

    spA.reset();
    spB->func1();
}
```

However before using the method of `B`, `func1()`, I would like to reset the `spA` pointer. But the object `spA` is pointing to, is not allowed to be destroyed yet (design requirement, because object pointed by `spB` can hold references on some of the `A`'s members).

To be able to do that I thought that `B` can also hold a pointer to `A`, lets say `A* m_A`. But since `B` is created from `A`'s constructor, there is no `A` object yet to initialize `m_A`.

Passing `this` in `A`'s constructor to `createB(this)` does not solve the problem, since it does not share ownership with `spA`, which is created in the first line of `main()`, so it does not prevent the object pointed by `spA` to be destroyed completely after `spA.reset()`.

Another alternative I had, was to make `m_A` a `shared_ptr`, but passing `shared_from_this()` in `A`'s constructor to `createB(this->shared_from_this())` is either impossible, since the `A` object has not been created yet.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Factory and setter?

Comment: @Jarod42, could you please elaborate in more detail?

Comment: Something like `std::shared_ptr<A> makeA() { auto a = std::make_shared<A>(/*private_key{}*/); auto b = a->getSpB(); b->setAptr(a); return a; }`. you probably want then to make constructors `private` to enforce the factory.